# Oscillating AVAudioPlayer Volume in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I'm trying to get the volume of an `AVAudioPlayer` to oscillate over time.

Ex: Every 10 seconds, adjust volume to 0.5, then to 1.0, etc.

I have tried using an `NSTimer` but it only works the first time and doesn't loop.

```
    oscillateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(oscillateRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

oscillateRun function

    - (void)oscillateRun {

    BOOL oscillation;
    oscillation = NO;

        if(oscillation = YES) {
            oscillation = NO;
            audioPlayer.volume = 0.50;
        }
        else {
            oscillation = YES;
            audioPlayer.volume = 1;
        }

}
```

Unsure what to do, thanks in advance!

Comment: what happend when you try like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here `problem` is that every time you are creating new bool variable and it takes every time NO that'why value there is no changes in volume of the `AVPlayer`.

create oscillation  object globally ,

```
 BOOL oscillation;
```

call this method like

```
  [self oscillateRun]; 

 - (void)oscillateRun {

            if(oscillation == YES) {
                oscillation = NO;
                [audioPlayer setVolume : 0.50];
            }
            else {
                oscillation = YES;
                [audioPlayer setVolume : 1.0];
            }
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(oscillateRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
```

EDIT:-

```
for camparing the two variables use '==' change this one in if condition then it'l works fine.
```

Comment: Where am I putting [self oscillateRun] ? I have my NSTimer currently in the audioPlayer function, you recommend moving that to the oscillateRun function?

Comment: @Steven Ritchie:you can place this one where you want to start the AVPlayer(playing audio).

Comment: This still doesn't work. It lowers the volume after the first interval, but does not raise it after another interval. I also use if(oscillation == YES) which was a typo in my initial code

Comment: @Steven Ritchie:once check my answer and it'l works fine now.

Comment: I figured it out on my own, putting the timer in the function was creating multiple instances of the timer in parallel, breaking it. Thanks though!